# How to send email with new lines in apex?

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage, textarea

In my app, there is a `lightning:textarea` in which the user can type the content that will be send as an email to the users. This is the textarea:
[image]
As you can see from the image, the 'Thanks' is after 2 lines of the first line. But when I send the mail, I get like  this:

[image]

In the mail, both sentences are on the same line. This is the code I used:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.toAddresses = new String[] { emailId };
message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
message.subject = emailSubject;
message.setSenderDisplayName(senderDisplay);
message.setHtmlBody(emailBody);//'emailBody' is the content from textarea
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

As the content in the textarea is typed by the user himself, he cannot put `<br/>` in it. He may not have the technical knowledge. Basically, each 'Enter' pressed by the user has to be a new line in the mail body.

Also, I know this will work if I use `setPlainTextBody(plainTextBody)`. But the problem with `setPlainTextBody(plainTextBody)` is that, **I also want to include `<a href>` links in the mail body**. Those links will not work if I use `setPlainTextBody(plainTextBody)`.

So, how can I solve that? How can I include both new lines and links in my email body?

Comment: Blank space between tags in html are ignored. You need to replace the enter/return character with BR tag.

Comment: thanks for the comment. how can i find the enter/return character?

Comment: \n is the return char. So try this `emailBody.replaceAll('\n', '<br/>');`

Comment: thanks very much. it worked.

Comment: @HengkyIlawan I think you should post that in answer.

Comment: I have put my comments as answer @rahulgawale!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank space between tags in html are ignored. You need to replace the enter/return character with `<br>` tag.
For example:

```java
emailBody.replaceAll('\n', '<br/>');
```